# Extend HttpServlet implement ServletContextListener

Tags: servlets, servletcontextlistener

Is it a good practice for a class to extend `HttpServlet` and implement `ServletContextListener`?

```
public Myclass extends HttpServlet implements ServletcontextListener {
}
```

What are the pros and cons of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- You will have at least two instances of your class. The container create one as `ServletContextListener` and at least one as `HttpServlet` when your servlet get an incoming request.
- Since the 2+ instances you cannot use instance (just static) members to share data.
- It's easier if other classes don't use the data/objects that you initialize and share in the listener because you don't have to put these data/objects to the application scope in the `ServletContextListener` and retrieve them in the `HttpServlet`.
- If your initialization logic is complex maybe it's worth to separate it from the servlet code (e.g. putting the initialization code to a different class and using the application scope to get the shared objects in the servlet).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on you, the implementer. [ServletcontextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) has its particular purpose. Make sure you know what it is for before using it.
In case you are creating an HTTP servlet you must extend [HttpServlet](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).If your class wants to "***receive notifications about changes to the servlet context of the web application***"  (copied from javadocs) it is part of, you have to implement ServletcontextListener.